# Call a servlet program when SQL trigger occurs

Tags: java, sql, servlets

Is there a way in which I can call a servlet program when an update occurs to the database or at a specific time or when a sql trigger occurs. Any library or reference would be useful. Thanks in advance

Comment: Please tag the RDBMS which you are using, as the answer may likely be sql platform-dependent.

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve? Describe complete use case. For example I can understand that PL/SQL will initiate HTTP request under certain condition you described.

Comment: Let me explain, let's say I have a relation in which I have some dates and corresponding descriptions. Now all I want to do is communicate to some people about the description as the date is approaching (say 7 days earlier)

Comment: How do you think that it will work? Servlet accepts connection from a browser, it does some job and returns data back. If you pass information from the timer or other asynchronous task, there is no HTTP request waiting.

Answer (score 2):

You can use client side timer which trigger with per-defined time period to check that DB updates happen in the database.Here we have to refresh the browser, for that we can use that client timer thing with the ajax support.